# gcc __thread local variables post fork() in a multi-threaded program

Tags: multithreading, gcc, fork, thread-local-storage

I'm using a 'regular C' program on X86 RHEL 8 and gcc 8.5. (Although I'll probably move on to RHEL 9).

If I have a multi-threaded program using some '__thread' global variables, and a thread from that program forks(), what happens to the copies of the parents allocated thread local variables in the child process?

Do the (presumably now unreachable) instances of the thread local variable that were created for 'the other' (non-forked) threads continue to exist in the child? Or are they de-allocated (in the child process) as if those threads had ended?

I think things like memory that had been malloc()ed from other threads would persist in the child, but I wasn't sure about global TLS variables.

I'm guessing that a 'copy' of the thread local storage for the thread that did the fork() ends up being used by the child process thread.

My concern is if these 'other' instances of TLS variables from the other parent threads end up in the child process, then would subsequent forks() keep accumulating additional 'unused' TLS data (or not).

In my case, I can't end the other threads before the fork() happens.

Comment: If the child process immediately calls `exec(...)` after the `fork()` returns, then there will be no thread-local variables. There will be no malloc()ed objects. Everything will be wiped clean. But if the child of a multi-threaded process does anything else after `fork()` returns, then you are heading into dangerous territory. (E.G., Thinking of calling `malloc()`? What if some other thread in the parent process happened to be in a malloc() call at the moment when the child was forked? The malloc() call in the child might never return in that case!!)

Comment: Yes, I also think that fork() without subsequent exec() in a multi-threaded environment is not a great idea due to all the consequences.

But in this case I have to maintain a legacy program system where I can only go so far in what I can now change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread-local storage is just memory, no different from thread-specific stack memory. As such, it will be mapped to the new process's address space. However, since there is only one thread in the new process, this memory cannot be easily accessed.

This should not be a concern since the memory is not copied, just mapped as copy-on-write. Nothing writes to that memory, so it's just another unused set of pages.

What should be a concern is all the locked mutexes that will exist in the child process, without threads to unlock them. But this is described many times elsewhere.